# Oracle HTTP Server "File name too long" ERROR

Tags: oracle, httpserver, long-filenames, oracle-http-server

I am using Oracle HTTP Server.
I would like to ask about my server log file. I saw an ERROR in my log file example like this:

```
[OHS] [ERROR:32] [AH00127] [core] [client_id: 10.10.10.10] [host_id: example] [host_addr: 10.10.10.10] [pid: 111111] [tid: 111111] [user: web] [ecid: 111111] [rid: 0] [VirtualHost: example.com.tr:5555] (36)File name too long: AH00127: Cannot map GET /example/...
```

This Error does not occur another Load Balancer. But I get in Oracle HTTP Server in a specific context path.

I know the solution for change the Linux file System limit from "255". But don't want to change the whole server for this particular error.

Any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you seen this similar question? The error might be more about your URL design than about a specific file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337891/apache-error-file-name-too-long-cannot-map-get